# JQuery select element with special characters in Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML where the Id contains special charaters:

```
<input type="text" id="e09b989c-7201-4b7e-8fd4-a2309db6d356|b5d9746a-7f7c-432d-a4ef-a5e0011d989d|IssueDate" name="e09b989c-7201-4b7e-8fd4-a2309db6d356|b5d9746a-7f7c-432d-a4ef-a5e0011d989d|IssueDate" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="Type_e09b989c-7201-4b7e-8fd4-a2309db6d356|b5d9746a-7f7c-432d-a4ef-a5e0011d989d|IssueDate" name="Type_e09b989c-7201-4b7e-8fd4-a2309db6d356|b5d9746a-7f7c-432d-a4ef-a5e0011d989d|IssueDate" value="date">
<br>
<input type="text" id="1c36b33a-85d8-4811-93f6-a5e000ad985c|b795c0b4-1c8b-4d9e-95c5-a5e0011d8505|FromDate(mm/dd/yyyy)" name="1c36b33a-85d8-4811-93f6-a5e000ad985c|b795c0b4-1c8b-4d9e-95c5-a5e0011d8505|FromDate(mm/dd/yyyy)" value="" class="">
<input type="hidden" id="Type_1c36b33a-85d8-4811-93f6-a5e000ad985c|b795c0b4-1c8b-4d9e-95c5-a5e0011d8505|FromDate(mm/dd/yyyy)" name="Type_1c36b33a-85d8-4811-93f6-a5e000ad985c|b795c0b4-1c8b-4d9e-95c5-a5e0011d8505|FromDate(mm/dd/yyyy)" value="DateTime">
```

And i am using this JQuery to update them:

```
 $("input[id^='Type_']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "date" || $(this).val() == "DateTime") {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("Type_", "").replace(/\|/g, "\\|").replace(/\//g, "\\\\\/").replace(/\)/g, "\\\\\)").replace(/\(/g, "\\\\\(");

           console.log(id);
           console.log(">>" + $("#" + id));

            $("#" + id).val(id);
        }
    });
```

But the second Id which contains "|" and "(" is not selected.
I am testing here: http://jsfiddle.net/MWadX/446/

Can somebody help me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are escaping the special characters,

```
var id = this.id.replace(/[|\(\)#\\\/]/g, '\\$&');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lw01vrz1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
            $("input[id^='Type_']").each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "date" || $(this).val() == "DateTime") {
                    var tempID = $(this).attr('id');
                    var temp_ID1 = this.id.replace(/[|\(\)#\\\/]/g, '\\$&');
                    console.log(temp_ID1);
                    console.log("#" + temp_ID1);
                }
            });
```